# NPM keeps using HTTPS eventhough I specify HTTP registry

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nexus

I have an NPM project set up for using a self-hosted NPM registry in Nexus. I need to access that repository via HTTP (I cannot change this), but no matter what I do, the resolved URL is always the HTTPS version of the registry.

I have this minimal project:

```
.
├── .npmrc
└── package.json
```

The `package.json` is really simple, too:

```json
{
  "name": "npm-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}
```

The `.npmrc` just contains the registry information:

```
registry=http://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/
```

I have also npm configuration at user level in `~/.npmrc`:

```
//my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/:_authToken=NpmToken.xxx
email=me@email.com
always-auth=true
//my.repository.com/repository/npm-private/:_authToken=NpmToken.xxx
```

If I'm in my project's directory and do `npm config ls -l` I get the following:

```
; "default" config from default values

_auth = (protected) 
access = null 
all = false 
allow-same-version = false 
also = null 
audit = true 
audit-level = null 
auth-type = "legacy" 
before = null 
bin-links = true 
browser = null 
ca = null 
cache = "/xxx/.npm" 
cache-max = null 
cache-min = 0 
cafile = null 
call = "" 
cert = null 
ci-name = null 
cidr = null 
color = true 
commit-hooks = true 
depth = null 
description = true 
dev = false 
diff = [] 
diff-dst-prefix = "b/" 
diff-ignore-all-space = false 
diff-name-only = false 
diff-no-prefix = false 
diff-src-prefix = "a/" 
diff-text = false 
diff-unified = 3 
dry-run = false 
editor = "/usr/bin/nano" 
engine-strict = false 
fetch-retries = 2 
fetch-retry-factor = 10 
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000 
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000 
fetch-timeout = 300000 
force = false 
foreground-scripts = false 
format-package-lock = true 
fund = true 
git = "git" 
git-tag-version = true 
global = false 
global-style = false 
globalconfig = "/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/etc/npmrc" 
heading = "npm" 
https-proxy = null 
if-present = false 
ignore-scripts = false 
include = [] 
include-staged = false 
include-workspace-root = false 
init-author-email = "" 
init-author-name = "" 
init-author-url = "" 
init-license = "ISC" 
init-module = "/xxx/.npm-init.js" 
init-version = "1.0.0" 
init.author.email = "" 
init.author.name = "" 
init.author.url = "" 
init.license = "ISC" 
init.module = "/xxx/.npm-init.js" 
init.version = "1.0.0" 
install-links = false 
json = false 
key = null 
legacy-bundling = false 
legacy-peer-deps = false 
link = false 
local-address = null 
location = "user" 
lockfile-version = null 
loglevel = "notice" 
logs-dir = null 
logs-max = 10 
; long = false ; overridden by cli
maxsockets = 15 
message = "%s" 
metrics-registry = "http://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/" 
node-options = null 
node-version = "v18.12.0" 
noproxy = [""] 
npm-version = "8.19.2" 
offline = false 
omit = [] 
omit-lockfile-registry-resolved = false 
only = null 
optional = null 
otp = null 
pack-destination = "." 
package = [] 
package-lock = true 
package-lock-only = false 
parseable = false 
prefer-offline = false 
prefer-online = false 
prefix = "/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0" 
preid = "" 
production = null 
progress = true 
proxy = null 
read-only = false 
rebuild-bundle = true 
; registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/" ; overridden by project
replace-registry-host = "npmjs" 
save = true 
save-bundle = false 
save-dev = false 
save-exact = false 
save-optional = false 
save-peer = false 
save-prefix = "^" 
save-prod = false 
scope = "" 
script-shell = null 
searchexclude = "" 
searchlimit = 20 
searchopts = "" 
searchstaleness = 900 
shell = "/bin/zsh" 
shrinkwrap = true 
sign-git-commit = false 
sign-git-tag = false 
sso-poll-frequency = 500 
sso-type = "oauth" 
strict-peer-deps = false 
strict-ssl = true 
tag = "latest" 
tag-version-prefix = "v" 
timing = false 
tmp = "/tmp" 
umask = 0 
unicode = true 
update-notifier = true 
usage = false 
user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch} workspaces/{workspaces} {ci}" 
userconfig = "/xxx/.npmrc" 
version = false 
versions = false 
viewer = "man" 
which = null 
workspace = [] 
workspaces = null 
workspaces-update = true 
yes = null 

; "user" config from /xxx/.npmrc

//my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/:_authToken = (protected) 
//my.repository.com/repository/npm-private/:_authToken = (protected) 
always-auth = true 
email = "me@mail.com" 

; "project" config from /xxx/npm-test/.npmrc

registry = "http://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/" 

; "cli" config from command line options

long = true
```

If I'm correct, there are no references to HTTPS version of the registry. But if I run `npm -ddd install`, I see the HTTPS version is used:

```
npm -ddd install
npm verb cli /xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/bin/node /xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/bin/npm
npm info using npm@8.19.2
npm info using node@v18.12.0
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/xxx/Documentos/Workspace/npm-test/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 6ms
npm timing config:load:file:/xxx/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 12ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
npm timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "--loglevel" "silly" "install"
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/xxx/.npm/_logs
npm verb logfile /xxx/.npm/_logs/2024-02-28T07_53_30_217Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 23ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm sill logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm sill logfile done cleaning log files
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 12ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
npm sill idealTree buildDeps
npm sill fetch manifest ts-node@^10.9.2
npm http fetch GET 200 https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/ts-node 812ms (cache miss)
npm sill fetch manifest @swc/core@>=1.2.50
npm http fetch GET 200 https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/@swc%2fcore 865ms (cache miss)
npm sill fetch manifest @swc/helpers@^0.5.0
npm http fetch GET 200 https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/@swc%2fhelpers 315ms (cache miss)
npm sill fetch manifest @swc/wasm@>=1.2.50
npm http fetch GET 200 https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/@swc%2fwasm 312ms (cache miss)
npm sill fetch manifest @types/node@*
npm http fetch GET 200 https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/@types%2fnode 1114ms (cache miss)
npm sill fetch manifest typescript@>=2.7
npm http fetch GET 200 https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/typescript 2213ms (cache miss)
...
```

And in `package-lock.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "npm-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "npm-test",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "devDependencies": {
        "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support": {
      "version": "0.8.1",
      "resolved": "https://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/@cspotcode/source-map-support/-/source-map-support-0.8.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-IchNf6dN4tHoMFIn/7OE8LWZ19Y6q/67Bmf6vnGREv8RSbBVb9LPJxEcnwrcwX6ixSvaiGoomAUvu4YSxXrVgw==",
      "dev": true,
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@jridgewell/trace-mapping": "0.3.9"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=12"
      }
    },
...
```

The `resolved` value is also the HTTPS version of my registry for all packages.

Am I missing something? I tried removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, running `npm cache clean --force` and then installing again, but the same happens.

I also tried setting `strict-ssl` to `false` in `.npmrc` but, again, no changes.

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Most web services will automatically route you to the HTTPS variant without you having to do anything. It might help us to understand why you're trying to do this?

Comment: Can you try to do one of the requests i.e. `http://my.repository.com/repository/npm-group/ts-node` with open devtools in the browser or in Postman to see if there is any redirection by the web server? (status code 3xx)

Comment: Indeed, there is a redirection set up in the server from HTTP to HTTPS. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: `I cannot change this` - Glad to see you've already found the answer. I think instead of "I cannot change this" it's more accurate to say "I don't need to change this because the server admins have already changed it for me". It's rare these days to find admins willingly expose http endpoints especially since you can get SSL certificates for free these days.

Comment: Well, @slebetman it's more "I cannot change this" because server admins won't let me change anything and, instead, keep saying that the problem was on my side haha. Finally yes, they admitted there was a redirection and chanted it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@j-cake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7792079/j-cake) and [@json-derulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470544/json-derulo) pointed out, there was a redirection at the server from HTTP to HTTPS.